# Maui, Xamarin: When AppThemeBinding Changes, some labels in AppShell arent re-rendered

Tags: xamarin, maui

I have in my shell menu this code:

```
<Shell.FlyoutFooter>
    <VerticalStackLayout Padding="10,0,0,0" Margin="0,0,0,10" HeightRequest="50">
        <Label Text="{Binding UserEmail}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White, Light=Black}" FontFamily="ook" FontSize="Medium"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding AppVersion, StringFormat='V. {0}'}" TextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White, Light=Black}" FontFamily="ook" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="Medium"/>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</Shell.FlyoutFooter>
```

It technically works, but If you switch the phones theme and then return back to the app WITHOUT closing and opening it again, these labels are not getting changed.

Its strange, because the rest inside this shell menu IS being rerendered correctly when the theme changes.
Is there any way to workaround this? Maybe force it to rerender? I tried working with

```
<Shell.Behaviors>
    <MTK:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="Appearing"  Command="{Binding ReLoadLogsCommand}"/>
</Shell.Behaviors>
```

OnAppearing (I am using MVVM) but this is not called when the app is resumed, so it was no use.

Any other ideas of fixes?

best,

J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET MAUI offers the **Application.RequestedThemeChanged** event. This event is raised whenever the app's requested theme changed.

- **Step 1** : Define the **IThemeService** interface.
  Create an interface that outlines the functionalities of your theme service.

```
public interface IThemeService
{
    event Action ThemeChanged;
    void NotifyThemeChanged();
}
```

- **Step 2** : Now, implement the IThemeService interface in a class.

```
public class ThemeService : IThemeService
{
    public event Action ThemeChanged;

    public void NotifyThemeChanged()
    {
        ThemeChanged?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

- **Step 3** : Register the Service with Dependency Injection. In your MauiProgram.cs or where you configure your services, register the ThemeService with the dependency injection container

```
// Register the theme service
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IThemeService, ThemeService>();
```

- **Step 4** : Inject and Use IThemeService in Your App. In your App.xaml.cs or relevant ViewModel, inject IThemeService to listen for theme changes and act accordingly.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private readonly IThemeService _themeService;

    public App(IThemeService themeService)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _themeService = themeService;

        // Subscribe to theme changes
        _themeService.ThemeChanged += OnThemeChanged;

        this.RequestedThemeChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            _themeService.NotifyThemeChanged();
        };
        ...
    }

    private void OnThemeChanged()
    {
        // Handle theme change
    }
}
```

- **Step 5** : Adjust ViewModel to Use IThemeService. In the viewModel subscribe to the ThemeService.ThemeChanged event, and update properties accordingly.

```
public class YourViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly IThemeService _themeService;

    public YourViewModel(IThemeService themeService)
    {
        _themeService = themeService;
        _themeService.ThemeChanged += OnThemeChanged;
    }

    private void OnThemeChanged()
    {
        // Update properties that depend on the theme
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UserEmail));
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AppVersion));
    }

    // Implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface
}
```

Comment: Thank you. that KINDA did the trick; the last step didnt do anything "onPropertyChanged" is called, but the strings are not updated to fit the new theme. I ended up now injecting your service inside the code behind and expose the strings to it. I just manually changed the color on OnThemeChanged in regards to what theme is active right now. Super unsexy and a lot of code for two strings but at least it works. Thank you!

Comment: another edit is that it now allows me to change the color once, if i change the theme again, thet handler is called but the color changes are completely ignored :D